# PHPExcel pattern style

Tags: php, phpexcel

Does anyone know the syntax to use to add pattern styles to the cell color? I would like to add a thin reverse diagonal stripe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, it's not possible.  In `\Style\Fill.php`, these appear to be the only choices, though there may be a newer version with more choices.

```
$worksheet->getStyle('A:C')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID);

/* Fill types */
const FILL_NONE                         = 'none';
const FILL_SOLID                        = 'solid';
const FILL_GRADIENT_LINEAR              = 'linear';
const FILL_GRADIENT_PATH                = 'path';
const FILL_PATTERN_DARKDOWN             = 'darkDown';
const FILL_PATTERN_DARKGRAY             = 'darkGray';
const FILL_PATTERN_DARKGRID             = 'darkGrid';
const FILL_PATTERN_DARKHORIZONTAL       = 'darkHorizontal';
const FILL_PATTERN_DARKTRELLIS          = 'darkTrellis';
const FILL_PATTERN_DARKUP               = 'darkUp';
const FILL_PATTERN_DARKVERTICAL         = 'darkVertical';
const FILL_PATTERN_GRAY0625             = 'gray0625';
const FILL_PATTERN_GRAY125              = 'gray125';
const FILL_PATTERN_LIGHTDOWN            = 'lightDown';
const FILL_PATTERN_LIGHTGRAY            = 'lightGray';
const FILL_PATTERN_LIGHTGRID            = 'lightGrid';
const FILL_PATTERN_LIGHTHORIZONTAL      = 'lightHorizontal';
const FILL_PATTERN_LIGHTTRELLIS         = 'lightTrellis';
const FILL_PATTERN_LIGHTUP              = 'lightUp';
const FILL_PATTERN_LIGHTVERTICAL        = 'lightVertical';
const FILL_PATTERN_MEDIUMGRAY           = 'mediumGray';
```

Answer (score 1):

Select the most appropriate pattern from those listed in GDP's answer for a horizontal or vertical, setting the appropriate colours and then setRotation() for the Fill:

```
$worksheet->getStyle('A1')->getFill()
    ->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_GRADIENT_LINEAR)
    ->setStartColor(new PHPExcel_Style_Color(PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOR_BLACK))
    ->setEndColor(new PHPExcel_Style_Color(PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOR_WHITE))
    ->setRotation(45);
```